# Best practices styling through properties

Tags: react-native

I'm new to react-native and I try to do my best to create clean code. I added a theme file with a palette I want to use all across my App.
How can I use my colors also for styling with component properties like the color property below:

```js
<MaterialCommunityIcons
  name={reverse ? 'arrow-up' : 'arrow-down'}
  style={styles.sortingArrow}
  size={20}
  color={'white'} />
```

How can I replace **white** with my theme color?

Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at theming with styled-components. By far the easy and painless setup for theming.

Comment: @BoraSumer tx, I will dive a bit into this one. But my question was not really about theming but about how to use my theme color for a property like the color property of the MaterialCommunityIcons. Thanks

Comment: I have to see your "theme colour". I don't see a theme colour in your code. I assume it is just a file with bunch of colours in it. So you can simply import that file into your component file by import theme from './theme'; and pass the property into colour prop like color={theme.palette.white}. Not sure the structure of your theme object so be careful about that, you may want to share it as well if you have any further issues.